# How can i solve a "Property 'checkValidity' does not exist on type 'Element'." ts(2339) error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having the above error with my code. I am learning how to make sure an html form doesn't submit without all fields been filed with values with bootstrap. The code i wrote which is written on their website as an example to how it is done, is below:

// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields

```
(() => {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

Now the error i get it that checkValidity() doesn't exist on type 'Element'. I have tried using "as any", casting it to an HTMLElement, HMLInputElement using the "<>" all to no avail.

Am I doing this wrong? Please put me through.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `document.querySelectorAll` is just `NodeListOf<Element>` as it doesn't take the selector into account (which is good in this case, as there might be non-form elements with class `needs-validation`).

You could add a conditional `if (form instanceof HTMLFormElement) { .. } else { .. }` to narrow the type, but if you use the [typed-query-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-query-selector) package, and refine the selector to `'form.needs-validation'`, the correct type will be inferred:

```
import 'typed-query-selector'

(() => {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form.needs-validation')
  // const forms: NodeListOf<HTMLFormElement>
  ..
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAchgTzAUwCYFoCOBXNKZLAZzQBs0BjGaBAKHoAomBKOAXgD44BveuIjxk4JGFGA0GAuAHpZcAGJoYVABZwAhuXJwYatHABm0ECTgB3Qxc0A7eLS1gw5ZHCrDaIOACEIEGDEoTTA4ADdtYAxNGGAIW1EUSnNaGSp4sWNTcw44DAgPEDR7ADp8QmQAZQpqWigAQR0mBBMoEBLbNEwSLAjyKJi42wRWGXlBQQA9AH5GQXGAGX9QiDDCPQNvOww4MCg0NftRPAAjEGASEiGZeqhg5BKjKAgQJlazVkfoAFFNdTfTJwePwJlk2iVNBgMN9DjAFhcYMVCM0SKdzjAEAAaOAHYrwbh8GSg4BGOBMACE7xK6moAGsAGqRDDAFBsdgg0ETXGlPbcmAAETQRk0eHIMDYRM5fJKYggYAACs8wJoAOaDeISzlwAC%20c05VKo5E0l3hYghUOaNh6fQGiIwI0l2uxwvIZFGgm1o09EqAA)

Comment: Following what you wrote in the typescript playground, i changed the part of the code to:

if (form instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
              if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
              }
            } else {
              form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }

It cleared the checkValidity() error but now i am having an error which says, "Can't resolve 'typed-query-selector'.

Comment: @VintageFarms You only have to do one of the two. Either use the if statement to narrow the type, or import the package and use selector `'form.needs-validation'`. If you use the package you'll need to install it first with `npm install typed-query-selector`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response. I was ill.